# Wicket embedded messages in fragment tries to get fragment from page model

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I have this very closing to working but the final hurdle is leaving me puzzled.
My use case: for a discussion panel I have to show a i18n message depending on the number of particants in the discussion. So, I have messages like:

- *From ${startedBy.displayName} to ${firstRecipients}*
- *From ${startedBy.displayName} to ${firstRecipients} and
  ${otherRecipientsCount} others*

I chose to use fragments for as this seemed to be the cleanest approach, so for each of the above messages I have a fragment. For the second one this is:

```
<wicket:fragment wicket:id="recipients_1toMany">
    <wicket:message key="heartbeat.wall.discussion.recipients.1toMany">
    <span wicket:id="startedBy.displayName"></span>
        <span wicket:id="firstRecipients"></span>
        <span wicket:id="otherRecipientsCount"></span>
    </wicket:message>
</wicket:fragment>
```

So, the wicket message will be compiled of the text + the variables of the embedded components (startedBy.displayName, ...).
This fragment will be added to following span:

```
<span wicket:id="recipientsPlaceHolder"></span>
```

The related java code:

```
public class DiscussionPanel extends Panel {

    public DiscussionPanel(final String id, final DiscussionTO discussion) {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<DiscussionTO>(discussion));

        ...

        final List<DiscussionParticipantTO> list = discussion.getParticipants();

        String fragmentId = "recipients_1toMany"; //actually depends on list.size()

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment("recipientsPlaceHolder", fragmentId, this);
        Label startedByLabel = new Label("startedBy.displayName");
        fragment.add(startedByLabel);
        this.add(fragment);

    }
}
```

This works like a charm. Now, the last hurdle, I need to render the *startedBy.displayName* as a link.

The html changes:

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="showUser">
    <span wicket:id="startedBy.displayName"></span>
</a>
```

The code changes:

```
    ExternalLink showUserLink = new ExternalLink("showUser", "someurl");
    showUserLink.add(startedByLabel);
    fragment.add(showUserLink);
```

So instead of adding the label (startedByLabel) to the fragment, I add the label to the link and add the link to the fragment.

Now I get following exception when the panel gets rendered:

```
Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: class com....DiscussionTO expression: recipientsPlaceHolder
     at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getGetAndSetter(PropertyResolver.java:499)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectAndGetSetter(PropertyResolver.java:341)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getObjectAndGetSetter(PropertyResolver.java:244)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.PropertyResolver.getValue(PropertyResolver.java:97)
     at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.getObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:134)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1639)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.WicketMessageResolver$MessageContainer$1.getValue(WicketMessageResolver.java:266)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.string.interpolator.VariableInterpolator.toString(VariableInterpolator.java:140)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.WicketMessageResolver$MessageContainer.renderMessage(WicketMessageResolver.java:249)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.resolver.WicketMessageResolver$MessageContainer.onComponentTagBody(WicketMessageResolver.java:208)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:72)
```

So, for some reason, somewhere down the chain to parse the message, it tries to find a getRecipientsPlaceHolder on (the model Object) DiscussionTO (see WicketMessageResolver in stacktrace).

It seems that if the message's variable (startedBy.displayName) does not correspond to the id of a child directly under the wicket:message tag that wicket is not able to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

As suspected wicket message resolver was looking for a child called 'startedBy.displayName' directly inside recipientsPlaceHolder. It will not go deeper than that. 
Either change the id of the link to 'startedBy.displayName' or, as I did, change the variable in the text resource to 'showUser'.